# Calling First or Second Query in Stored Procedure According To Condition

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like that;

```
AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      I.IslemNo, S.SahisID, I.MukayyitID,
      K.BirimKisim, M.SorusturmaNo, S.KimlikNo, S.Ad, S.Soyad 
   FROM
      [Ifade.MukayyittenSahsa] M 
   INNER JOIN 
      [Ifade.SahislarKimlikTablosu] S ON M.SahisID = S.SahisID
   INNER JOIN
      [Ifade.Islem] I ON M.SahisID = I.SahisID 
   INNER JOIN
      [Ifade.Kullanicilar] K ON I.MukayyitID = K.KullaniciNo 
   WHERE
      M.SorusturmaNo = @SorusturmaNo 
      AND S.KimlikNo = @KimlikNo;
//INSERT STATEMENT
```

In Winforms side: if the stored procedure generates 0 rows, I want to execute an insert statement inside the same stored procedure.

How can I do that or is it possible?
Note: It will be after DialogResult option at winform side..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@@ROWCOUNT` to get the number of affected rows in the last statement. See more info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx).

In your case you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  I.IslemNo, S.SahisID, I.MukayyitID,
  K.BirimKisim, M.SorusturmaNo, S.KimlikNo, S.Ad, S.Soyad 
FROM
  [Ifade.MukayyittenSahsa] M 
INNER JOIN 
  [Ifade.SahislarKimlikTablosu] S ON M.SahisID = S.SahisID
INNER JOIN
  [Ifade.Islem] I ON M.SahisID = I.SahisID 
INNER JOIN
  [Ifade.Kullanicilar] K ON I.MukayyitID = K.KullaniciNo 
WHERE
  M.SorusturmaNo = @SorusturmaNo 
  AND S.KimlikNo = @KimlikNo;

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    INSERT abcd
```

Comment: But basically i want it will be done with user dialogresult option selection that will send a value; If OK parameter will load 1 value and CASE WHEN will exequte Insert Statement ELSE doesnt

Comment: That's fine, you can add what you want in the select statement, what matters is that you check number of affected rows by checking `@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: Ok understood but I will try to find a solution with Select Case Statement. Thanks for Reply